# How to write your google analytic code in places other than header in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is there any way I can write my google analytic code somewhere else in my angular project and not write it straight inside my head. I know i cant hide my id but just wanted to make my code more clean while viewing on browser.If possible will love solutions in Typescript.

Just want my hide my script tag in dom.

Comment: For single-page applications you can/should use the **Google Tag Manager**. Just include the GA4 and GTM snippet, and configure the GTM to send the **historyChange** events to GA

Comment: I've written about it [here](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/angular-or-react-or-whatever-and-google-analytics-97342c909e61)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party plugin such as [ngx-google-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-google-analytics). This will give you more control in each page of your single page application. Then fire the pageview event by calling their pageView() function and pass the page title corresponding to each of your page path in pageview event for segregating the individual pages in GA.

Comment: I just want to hide my extra code in the header part, that's all. I don't want extra control or something just tell me how I can hide its script when it loads in browser while inspecting.

Comment: Move the code in <script> tag to a separate js file and add reference to the file if you just need to hide the script while inspecting in browser.